# mysql 5.6 update fail: Cannot select from table testDataBase.tableX

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```sql
UPDATE tableM m 
SET m.value = (
    SELECT
        sum( x.value ) AS valuesum 
    FROM
        tableX x,
        tableA a 
    WHERE
        x.code = m.code 
        AND x.city_id = a.city_id2 
        AND a.area_id = m.area_code 
        AND x.prov_id = m.prov_id 
        AND x.day_id = '20210127' 
    ) 
WHERE
    m.prov_id != '123' 
    AND m.area_code != '111' 
    AND m.target_code LIKE 'code1%';
```

mysql version is 5.6.16

i have three tables, want update tableM.value with sum(tableX.value), but Currently, this returns an error

> 1815 - [9001, 2022101809572201017706408320000417278] : Access Denied: Cannot select from table testDataBase.tableX .

---

try to use JOIN but fail

```sql
UPDATE tableT t
JOIN (
SELECT sum(valuesum) vSum, tCode FROM (
SELECT sum( x.target_value ) AS valuesum, x.target_code AS tCode
    FROM tableX x, tableA a, tableT b
    WHERE x.city_id = a.city_id2
      AND x.day_id = '20221017' 
        AND x.target_code = b.target_code 
        AND x.prov_id = b.prov_id 
        AND a.area_id = b.area_code 
        GROUP BY x.target_code)
) res
 ON t.target_code LIKE res.tCode 
 SET t.target_value = res.vSum
WHERE t.prov_id <> '111'
    AND t.area_code <> '-1'
    AND t.target_code LIKE 'code1%'
```

> 1815 - [15019, 2022101810360001017706408220000892416] It is not a currently supported update statement.

---

What is the proper syntax? thx

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text. Also in your JOIN code group by x.code in r and remove the test  x.CODE = m.CODE

Comment: @P.Salmon i add GROUP BY in JOIN code, but fail, tips: It is not a currently supported update statement.
and i update new sql in question

Comment: I am _personally afraid_ of this type of `UPDATE` query. I would rather create a temp table, insert the corresponding data and do the update with simple `JOIN`.. at least that way I can check the temp table if the data are correct before I do the update.

Comment: To be honest the code attempts are so bad that I can't reverse engineer intent or generate data to provide a solution - do consider publishing sample date and desired outcome as text.